# How to restore my keyboard to default settings?

Tags: keyboard, settings, keybindings

I was using Google Colab on my web browser and was trying to set some keyboard shortcut on Google Colab.

After that, my keyboard keep showing weird letters when I am typing. You can see it in this image:

[image]

I tried to solve this by going to `system preferences > keyboard`. Then setting shortcuts and input sources to defaults. But it is not working. I tried various other approaches from articles on the internet but I still couldn't fix it.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Mac version - macOS Mojave version 10.14.5

Web browser - Firefox version 74.0

Just to clarify, the problem is not totally related to the Firefox browser. It is also happening when I am using any other applications on my system like the text editor for writing code etc. It is a system wide problem.

Comment: Please add the version of macOS and what browsers you are using and that version as well to your original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour in macOS since 2011 is to display a menu of accent characters when holding down keys on the keyboard.

If you don't like this behaviour, you can go into the Terminal and disable it:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

> Once you’ve executed the command, log out and log back in to your user account. When you log back in, the accented characters will be disabled. Pressing and holding down a key on your keyboard will only repeat it.

This tip originated from https://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/disable-accented-characters-on-macos/